Texture Paint not working or being weird
I'm not sure what I did but I keep having this issue where I'm unable to paint with my brush or the color is really light. I don't think its an opacity or blending mode issue. I'm new to blender so I don't know what I can do to fix it.
The really light line is the issue, it used to look like the other lines. Has this happened to anyone else?

hello could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Welcome! Do you have the time to append the object into a new file and test it to see if the same issue is present away from the current file? Can you turn pressure off and still get the darker line there in the middle of the hammer, or does it come back to the lighter value?

In the left area (where the texture image is show), you need to go to paint mode.


Unfortunately that didn't change anything :(
